# In script : ssh and then sudo rootsh root

Tags: shell-script, ssh, whoami

Can't find the solution.
I need in the script - ssh to a server then change to root via `sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root`. Then make some action then go back and carry on with script... Something like

```
...
ssh -t myserver << EOF 
sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i- -u root
whoami
#<action on myserver as root>
EOF
...
```

If I do it this way - doesn't work.

If done in the way

```
ssh -t myserver 'sudo /usr/bin/rootsh -i -u root ;whoami'
```

I can do ssh and then switch to root, but then script wait until session/shell closed.

Comment: What is `rootsh`? Why not use `sudo` or `su` to become root directly? Why is this extra thing needed?

Comment: If you want the script to keep running in the background without waiting for session exit, you can use `nohup` or `command &` and then `disown -h`